# The best way of plotting a forecast line in Matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

The title of the question is a little focused, but in general, i am wondering if there is a more efficient way of having a different line style for parts of a line in matplotlib.

For example, I have random data in a single column dataframe:

```
           0
0   0.750712
1   0.568953
2   0.270217
3   0.912791
4   0.313565
5   0.428776
6   0.874447
7   0.437500
8   0.295404
9   0.628610
```

However, index values 5-9 are forecast values, hence when I graph them I want the line to be, in this case, red and dashed, to help differentiate them from the rest of the data.

The only way I know is a normal second line plot, but this duplicates the data, and I think would be problematic and inefficient for a more complex data set with multiple columns:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df[0], 'r--')
ax.plot(df.iloc[0:5, 0], 'b')
plt.show()
```

Which produces:

[image]

Is this the best way of achieving this? Or is there a parameter I am unaware of that will tell matplot lib that at x value n, use a different style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this example,](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/color_by_yvalue.html#sphx-glr-gallery-color-color-by-yvalue-py) a simple solution can be :

```
df=pd.DataFrame(rand(10))
x= arange(10)
valid,forecast = x<=4,x>=4
plot(x,ma.MaskedArray(df,~valid),'b',x,ma.MaskedArray(df,~forecast),'r--')
```

For

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear from the question what "best" would mean. Best try to avoid "best" when asking questions.

An easy way is to directly use pandas.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"y" : np.random.rand(10)})

ax = df.iloc[:5,:].plot(ls="-", color="b")
df.iloc[4:,:].plot(ls="--", color="r", ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If "best" relates to efficiency with respect to drawtime, a `LineCollection` is the best way.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

df = pd.DataFrame({"y" : np.random.rand(10)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

points = np.array([df.index.values, df["y"].values]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1],points[1:]], axis=1)

colors = plt.cm.bwr_r((df.index < 4).astype(float))
ls = ["-"]*4 + ["--"]*5
lc = LineCollection(segments, colors=colors, linestyles=ls )
ax.add_collection(lc)

ax.autoscale_view()

plt.show()
```

[image]